# Wordpress custom author urls

Tags: wordpress

I want to implement custom author urls.

Currently the author urls are like this:
http://site.com/author/author-name/

I want to do something like
http://site.com/my-custom-url-here

For each individual user.
I have tried using `author_rewrite_rules` filter, using the following code, this converts the url correctly but this gives me a page not found message when i browse the url

```
add_filter('author_link', 'no_author_base', 1000, 3);  
function no_author_base($link, $author_id) {  
    $link_base = trailingslashit(get_option('home'));  
    $link = preg_replace("|^{$link_base}author/|", '', $link);  
    return $link_base . $link;  
}  
add_filter('author_rewrite_rules', 'no_author_base_rewrite_rules');  
function no_author_base_rewrite_rules($author_rewrite) {    
    global $wpdb;  
    $author_rewrite = array();  
    $authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_nicename AS nicename from $wpdb->users");  
    foreach($authors as $author) {  
        $author_rewrite["({$author->nicename})/page/?([0-9]+)/?$"] = 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]';  
        $author_rewrite["({$author->nicename})/?$"] = 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]';  
    }     
    return $author_rewrite;  
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.
**UPDATE**

Problem is solved!, basically i did not know about calling the `flush_rewrite_rules` function.

Comment: After you implemented the code, did you visit the admin -> permalinks page to flush the rewrite rules?

Comment: @diggy i did not know about it, i learned about it over here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5413/need-help-with-add-rewrite-rule see my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

Here's how i did it:

i did not need the `author_link` filter so i removed it, my custom urls are stored in usermeta table so i fetched them and passed them into the rewrite array, and most importantly **I DID NOT KNOW ABOUT FLUSHING THE REWRITE CACHE AND THAT WAS THE REASON MY ORIGINAL CODE WAS NOT WORKING**

Heres the full code:

```
add_filter('author_rewrite_rules', 'my_author_url_with_custom_url_rewrite_rules');
function my_author_url_with_custom_url_rewrite_rules($author_rewrite) {

  global $wpdb;
  $author_rewrite = array();
  $authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, user_nicename AS nicename, meta_value as profile_name
                                    from $wpdb->users 
                                    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_usermeta.user_id = $wpdb->users.ID
                                    WHERE  meta_key = 'profile_name'");    

  foreach ($authors as $author) {
    $author_rewrite["{$author->profile_name}/page/?([0-9]+)/?$"] = 'index.php?author_name=' . $author->nicename . '&paged=$matches[1]';
    $author_rewrite["{$author->profile_name}/?$"] = "index.php?author_name={$author->nicename}";
  }
  return $author_rewrite;
}
flush_rewrite_rules(false);
```

dont forget to comment the `flush_rewrite_rules` call after you are done with rewrite rules, it is very expensive!

Comment: does this work in WP 3.8.1? It isn't working for me even after flushing permalinks

Answer (score 1):

try this one. for get your author url.

```
<?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
```

if post a admin or a author and want to show his/her all post in one page. so, you need to get his/her url automatic. **then try this one**

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question, that is about **customizing** the author URLs.